# Typescript overloads using an argument value to define the type of another parameter

Tags: typescript, casting, overloading, type-assertion

I have this piece of code (simplified example):

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gQgKQKIGEAqB9AglAvFAInmXWwIG4AoUSWRVTOPQ4hjOC68aV0lZovT6cutYhgCSAOWa9MOAD50SjKErkYUo6GgCaABSQBlSTPyCVZNSyGMC1i2xQFtyjDACqaWbezWNTOq+WpQAZgCuAHYAxsAAlgD2kVAAzgkAthAAYlGxiZEAFAkARgBWAFzKbFgANFA0EJWOpFgEAJSVGlhhufFJqRnZvflFZZ2+cHUNTQHt45ZwPTF9yWmZOcsjJRVVfFPcM8Fzu5haEZv9a0MXhdvzpvuQlXqGJtIdbp7eAN6UUP9QOKhKAFBp4XDmLrtKC-AFwqAAJwgwHCCOSAHEkJguqNSlAAIYpE7YNpUOEAXz+AIgABsUtAgSCwRDIRNobD4f8kSi0VBMdiJriCUSAqSqf9KXDafSYeL4dzURise5gkLCcSUGKKZRKZQlnl+vyVZYsLj5tUPl1ZXCFbztjq9ecDUqBQszcS4JaJtaAbbkvbdU6VnzlRoUO6w17LPwOVzkYqoAGgA)

It's basically an overloaded function that might get 3 different types of object, and will call a different function to each type. I'm differentiating the calls by passing a `type` parameter that should define the `obj` type and the return type.

```typescript
type OBJECT_A = "OBJECT_A";
type OBJECT_B = "OBJECT_B";
type OBJECT_C = "OBJECT_C";

type OBJ_IN = OBJECT_A | OBJECT_B | OBJECT_C
type TYPES_IN = "OBJECT_A" | "OBJECT_B" | "OBJECT_C"
type OBJ_OUT = OBJECT_A | OBJECT_B | OBJECT_C

function someFunction(obj: OBJECT_A, type: "OBJECT_A"): OBJECT_A
function someFunction(obj: OBJECT_B, type: "OBJECT_B"): OBJECT_B
function someFunction(obj: OBJECT_C, type: "OBJECT_C"): OBJECT_C
function someFunction(obj: OBJ_IN, type: TYPES_IN): OBJ_OUT {
    if (type === "OBJECT_A") {
        return GET_OBJECT_A(obj as OBJECT_A);   // <<<<< TYPE ASSERTION HERE
    }
    else if (type === "OBJECT_B") {
        return GET_OBJECT_B(obj as OBJECT_B);   // <<<<< TYPE ASSERTION HERE
    }
    else {
        return GET_OBJECT_C(obj as OBJECT_C);   // <<<<< TYPE ASSERTION HERE
    }
}


function GET_OBJECT_A(obj: OBJECT_A): OBJECT_A {
    return obj
}

function GET_OBJECT_B(obj: OBJECT_B): OBJECT_B {
    return obj
}

function GET_OBJECT_C(obj: OBJECT_C): OBJECT_C {
    return obj
}
```

**Note:** In this example I've simplified the return type to be as the same type of the `obj`. In my real case the return type is kind of a `Partial<OBJECT>` for each case.

**QUESTION**

My question is why is Typescript demanding those type assertions? If I'm already checking `type === "OBJECT_A`, isn't it already clear (from the overload signatures) that `obj` must be of type `OBJECT_A`?

Is there a better pattern to handle this? Or should I just stick with the type assertions?

Without the type assertions, Typescript will complain about the calls:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

The idea for the `type` parameter was to avoid creating functions to check if the `obj` was type `A | B | C`, like `function IS_OBJECT_A(obj) : obj is OBJECT_A`, etc. I would have to check for properties, or something like that. The idea is that when I pass `type: "OBJECT_A"` the only overload call that allows it should make sure that `obj` is of course `obj: OBJECT_A`.

Comment: If you're going to need to hardcode the string in a call to `someFunction` (e.g., `someFunction(obj, "OBJECT_A")`, it might be simpler just to have separate functions (e.g., `someFunctionA(obj)`) rather than an overloaded function...? (That said: I know there's a way to do this, and I'm frustrated that I'm not seeing it. :-) )

Comment: Thanks, TJ. That might be a solution. Since they all do basically the same thing, the only difference being that they operate on different objects, I was trying to keep as a single function. The overloads also work, though. They avoid making wrong calls like `someFunction(obj as OBJECT_A,"OBJECT_B")`. It will trigger an error. I'm just looking if there is a more efficient pattern to define the `obj` that goes in and which one should go out.